# Regular Expression using vbscript for starting characters

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to write regular expression for a string that should start with `"AET"` or `"BUS"` and then `'_'` and some string and then `'_'` then rest with any string. 
Ex:

```
<AET/BUS>_<text>_....
```

I need to capture this pattern.

I tried writing it as:

```
.pattern = "(AET|BUS)_*_*"
```

But this is not working for me.

Can you please help me writing the regular expression for the pattern.
Ex:

```
<AET/BUS>_<text>_....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
"^(AET|BUS)_.*_"
```

This will match any string that starts with either `AET` or `BUS`, followed by an underscore, followed by zero or more of any character, followed by an underscore.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me. But can you please tell me what does '.*' do hear. I mean why not only '*'.

Comment: @Srekk The `.` means 'any character', the `*` means 'zero or more'. BTW, the `^` means 'the start of string (or line in multiline mode)'.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "then rest with any string", what do you mean? When should the string stop?

`^(AET|BUS)_.*?_`

Should perform a non-greedy search matching from AET_ or BUS_ to the next _ it finds and then stop. If you need to capture more characters after the second _, which it sounds like you do, you'll need to define when the search should end somehow, unless you want to grab EVERYTHING after.

Answer (score 0):

This usage is greedy first match.
It won't match another `_` between `_`'s. Its faster than non-greedy, yet is a minimal match.

```
 ^(AET|BUS)_[^_]*_
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I need formatting to make @mrres1 to see the light:

```
>> set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "<(AET|BUS)>_{1}([^_]){1,}_{1}(.){1,}"
>> set ms = r.Execute("<BUS>_TESTTEST_!@#$%^&*()")
>> WScript.Echo ms(0).Submatches(0)
>> WScript.Echo ms(0).Submatches(1)
>> WScript.Echo ms(0).Submatches(2)
>>
BUS
T
)
>> r.Pattern = "<(AET|BUS)>_{1}([^_]{1,})_{1}(.{1,})"
>> set ms = r.Execute("<BUS>_TESTTEST_!@#$%^&*()")
>> WScript.Echo ms(0).Submatches(0)
>> WScript.Echo ms(0).Submatches(1)
>> WScript.Echo ms(0).Submatches(2)
>>
BUS
TESTTEST
!@#$%^&*()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<(AET|BUS)>_{1}([^_]){1,}_{1}(.){1,}
```

This will make three captures, "AET" or "BUS" for 1, the "<text>" for 2, and the "......." for 3.

If you want to capture the underlines you can just move them to the inside of the the parenthesis.

For example, these all match the pattern:

```
<AET>_<text>_....
<BUS>_<text>_....
<AET>_test123_test
<BUS>_TESTTEST_!@#$%^&*()
```

Comment: please test your regexp and correct your answer (the grouping () need to include the qualifiers).

Comment: The qualifiers are `AET` or `BUS` for 1, any character except a `_` goes into 2, and any character `.` for 3.  The expression will only match when that entire pattern is matched, although only part of the information is being captured.

Comment: again: please test your regexp.

Comment: Mine is matching, what's the problem?